# Autogenerating ID column when doing COPY from CSV

Tags: postgresql, csv

I have a simple table (4 text columns, and an ID column). I am trying to import my CSV file which has no ID column.

In Postico I have the schema setup as such:
[image]

```
DROP TABLE changes;
CREATE TABLE changes(
id    SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
commit_id TEXT,
additions INTEGER,
deletions INTEGER,
file_id TEXT
);
CREATE TEMP TABLE tmp_x AS SELECT * FROM changes LIMIT 0;
COPY tmp_x(commit_id,additions,deletions,file_id) FROM '/Users/George/git-parser/change_file' (format csv, delimiter E'\t');
INSERT INTO changes SELECT * FROM tmp_x
ON CONFLICT DO NOTHING;
DROP TABLE tmp_x;
```

But I am getting the error `ERROR:  null value in column "id" violates not-null constraint`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to specify the columns:

```
COPY tmp_x (commit_id, additions, deletions, file_id) 
FROM '/Users/George/git-parser/change_file' (format csv, delimiter E'\t');
```

The order of columns specified in the `copy` statement must obviously match the order of the columns in the input file.

---

You need to change your `insert` statement as well.

```
INSERT INTO changes SELECT * FROM tmp_x
```

will insert **all** columns from `tmp_x` into the target table, but as you did not define the `id` column as `serial` in the `tmp_x` table, nothing got generated and `null` values were inserted. And your `insert` statement just copies those null values.

You need to skip the `id` column in the `insert` statement:

```
INSERT INTO changes (commit_id,additions,deletions,file_id) 
SELECT commit_id,additions,deletions,file_id
FROM tmp_x
ON CONFLICT DO NOTHING;
```

You can actually remove the `id` column from `tmp_x`

Comment: I inspected the TEMP table `SELECT * FROM tmp_x;` and the ID column is empty. 
Query error: ERROR:  null value in column "id" violates not-null constraint
DETAIL:  Failing row contains (7dc8ca21c5d5abd4bec9e2ad4a8f9a7bff079878, 5, 0, 0|CONTRIBUTING.md, null).

Comment: You need to define the `id` columns as `serial`

Comment: Check out the updated code. I added my table construction. Still getting the same `null value in column "id"`.