# IntegrityError null value in column "id" after importing DB to postgresql

Tags: django, postgresql, import

UPDATE: Solved it by updating the lastval in the id sequence

`SELECT pg_catalog.setval('public.products_product_id_seq', max(id), false);`

where `max(id)` is `select max(id) from products_product`

I had my database on mysql and when I tried to import it into postgresql using several tools, it failed multiple times.

I decided to export csvs for every table and then importing them into postgres using COPY.

```
COPY products_product(id, name, unit_price, timestamp, updated, description, 
category_id, minimum_stock, qrcode, stock, unit, owner_id) 
FROM '~/csv/products.csv' DELIMITER ';' CSV HEADER;
```

After the import, I am able to update all of my models, regardless of the view I use to do so (I tried on the admin as well).

However, when I try to create a new object (doesn't matter which one), I get a `IntegrityError` like: `null value in column "id" violates not-null constraint`. (Tried on the admin as well).

The issue is the same across all of my models and all of my views, which led me to believe there must be something wrong with my postgres database after the import (perhaps with the primary key counter?). Because just after running migration and before I imported anything, I was able to create objects.

How can I fix this problem? Is there a configuration or something I must change on postgres or is there something about Django I'm not aware of?

If you're curious about my models:

```
class Product(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(
        max_length=120,
        null=False,
        blank=False,
        verbose_name='Nombre')
    description = models.TextField(
        blank=True,
        null=True,
        verbose_name='Descripción')
    category = models.ForeignKey(
        'Category',
        on_delete=models.SET_NULL,
        null=True,
        blank=True,
        verbose_name='Categoría')
    unit_price = models.PositiveIntegerField(
        default=0,
        null=False,
        blank=False,
        verbose_name='Precio unitario')
    unit = models.CharField(
        max_length=255,
        default='ud',
        blank=True)
    image = models.ImageField(
        upload_to='images/products',
        blank=True,
        null=True,
        verbose_name='Imagen')
    qrcode = models.ImageField(
        upload_to='qrcode',
        blank=True,
        null=True)
    stock = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    minimum_stock = models.PositiveIntegerField(default=0)

    owner = models.ForeignKey(
        'users.Company',
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
        related_name='products')
    timestamp = models.DateTimeField(
        default=timezone.now,
        null=True)
    updated = models.DateTimeField(
        auto_now=True,
        null=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

And what my postgress table for it looks like:

```
Table "public.products_product"
    Column     |           Type           | Collation | Nullable |         Default         
---------------+--------------------------+-----------+----------+-------------------------
 id            | integer                  |           | not null | 
 name          | character varying(120)   |           | not null | NULL::character varying
 description   | text                     |           |          | 
 unit_price    | integer                  |           | not null | 
 unit          | character varying(255)   |           | not null | NULL::character varying
 image         | character varying(100)   |           |          | 
 qrcode        | character varying(100)   |           |          | NULL::character varying
 stock         | integer                  |           | not null | 
 minimum_stock | integer                  |           | not null | 
 timestamp     | timestamp with time zone |           |          | 
 updated       | timestamp with time zone |           |          | 
 category_id   | integer                  |           |          | 
 owner_id      | integer                  |           | not null | 1
Indexes:
    "products_product_pkey" PRIMARY KEY, btree (id)
    "products_product_category_id_9b594869" btree (category_id)
    "products_product_owner_id_f189d068" btree (owner_id)
Check constraints:
    "products_product_minimum_stock_check" CHECK (minimum_stock >= 0)
    "products_product_unit_price_check" CHECK (unit_price >= 0)
Foreign-key constraints:
    "products_product_category_id_9b594869_fk_products_category_id" FOREIGN KEY (category_id) REFERENCES products_category(id) DEFERRABLE INITIALLY DEFERRED
    "products_product_owner_id_f189d068_fk_users_company_id" FOREIGN KEY (owner_id) REFERENCES users_company(id) DEFERRABLE INITIALLY DEFERRED
Referenced by:
    TABLE "expenses_item" CONSTRAINT "expenses_item_product_id_551c230a_fk_products_product_id" FOREIGN KEY (product_id) REFERENCES products_product(id) DEFERRABLE INITIALLY DEFERRED
    TABLE "orders_item" CONSTRAINT "orders_item_product_id_260e6ee8_fk_products_product_id" FOREIGN KEY (product_id) REFERENCES products_product(id) DEFERRABLE INITIALLY DEFERRED
    TABLE "quotations_item" CONSTRAINT "quotations_item_product_id_fa055ee8_fk_products_product_id" FOREIGN KEY (product_id) REFERENCES products_product(id) DEFERRABLE INITIALLY DEFERRED
```

And sample csv data:

```
"id";"name";"unit_price";"timestamp";"updated";"description";"category_id";"minimum_stock";"qrcode";"stock";"unit";"owner_id"
1;"Tote bag";1;"2018-07-24 17:05:37.631487";"2018-12-24 17:05:37.631487";"";;0;"";0;"ud";1
4;"Canvas bag";280;"2018-07-29 22:43:58.015396";"2018-12-29 22:43:58.015396";"";;0;"";0;"ud";1
5;"T-shirt";400;"2018-07-29 22:44:39.847575";"2018-12-29 22:45:06.463699";"";;0;"";0;"ud";1
```

Comment: add sample csv data

Comment: You should probably set a `default` for `id` (define a sequence to "autodispatch" ids).

Comment: @ShafikurRahman just added it at the end.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem should I set the default on the model? how can I define that sequence?

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem I think I figured out what you meant. I created a fresh database and migrated again, and now I do have a sequence `nextval('products_product_id_seq'::regclass)`. But I have a new problem: the counter seems to start at 1. After refreshing the page multiple times and getting: `IntegrityError: duplicate key value violates unique constraint "products_product_pkey" DETAIL:  Key (id)=(1) already exists`, then key id=2 and so on, I managed to create a product. I'll try to set up a default.

Comment: `SELECT pg_catalog.setval('public.products_product_id_seq', max(id), false);` did the trick. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You can try removing `id` from postgres copy command and ids from csv.
Like

```
COPY products_product(name, unit_price, timestamp, updated, description, 
category_id, minimum_stock, qrcode, stock, unit, owner_id) 
FROM '~/csv/products.csv' DELIMITER ';' CSV HEADER;
```

Comment: I didn't want to try that, because other models have a `ForeignKey` to these products. Is there away I can preserve that relationship while removing the `id`?

Comment: I don't know this. You can try this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35161432/autogenerating-id-column-when-doing-copy-from-csv

Comment: Thanks! I'll check that out